# KDB select regex from

Tags: kdb

Is there a way to use a regex for defining all the columns in a select statement. something like

```
select myColumnPrefix* from myTable
```

that would show all columns that start with myColumnPrefix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not using qSQL, however you can use a regex to get the column names and then use a functional select. For example,

```
c: cols[myTable] where cols[myTable] like "myColumnPrefix*";
?[myTable;();0b;c!c]
```

Or as a one-liner,

```
?[myTable;();0b;{x!x@:where x like "myColumnPrefix*"} cols myTable]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use qSQL (not advised - difficult to read/maintain) then you could expand on what @ostewart suggested:

Define table:

```
q)t:([]foo1:1 2;foo2:3 4;foo3:5 6;bar1:1 2;bar2:3 4;bar3:5 6)
q)t
foo1 foo2 foo3 bar1 bar2 bar3
-----------------------------
1    3    5    1    3    5
2    4    6    2    4    6
```

Extract columns of interest and prepare as string:

```
q)c:", " sv string cols[t] where cols[t] like "foo*";
q)c
"foo1, foo2, foo3"
```

Join columns to select query and value expression:

```
q)value "select ",c," from t"
foo1 foo2 foo3
--------------
1    3    5
2    4    6
```